# How do I access a field value for an entity (e.g. node) object?

Tags: 8, entities

`node_load((int) $nid)` loads a fully-populated node entity. `$node->title->value` gets the title, but how do I access field values in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

I guess you do not need to convert `$entity` into an array,
this would simply work.

```
$entity->get('field_name')->getValue();
```

Alternatively, we can make it easier to read as follows:

```
$entity->field_name->value;
```

FYI : Using `kint()` from the `devel_kint` module will let you know all the available methods that could be used to access the object elements, so comparatively `var_dump()` is less helpful.

Comment: Actually it should be: **$entity->get('field_name')->value;**

Comment: Do you know why this is @EdHollinghurst? getValue does indeed error for me, but (using dpm) it is listed in the available methods, whereas 'value' is not.

Comment: `getValue()` works for me (both on 8.1.x and 8.2.x) [see api reference](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21field%21FieldPluginBase.php/function/FieldPluginBase%3A%3AgetValue/8.2.x)

Comment: This is the best answer as it both works and agrees with [field_get_items() is replaced by the Entity Translation API](https://www.drupal.org/node/2055615).

Comment: `->getValue()` is generic and will works regardless of the field type. If you use `->value`, it only works if the field value is stored in a `value` property. It will not work for more complex types (eg. date or entity reference).

Comment: This code alone will throw an error if the entity doesn't have a field named "field_name".  Make sure this code only gets run on entities where you know that field exists, you can use $entity->hasField('field_name') to test, or if (!empty($entity->field_name))

Comment: @EdHollinghurst This is not always true. ->value doesn't work for multivalue fields. You'll get null returned.

Answer (score 73):

in drupal 8 , $node being of class node

```
 $node->field_machine_name->getValue();
```

or

```
$node->get('field_machine_name')->getValue();
```

will return an array of values.

If you expect only one, you might as well stringify the array with

```
$node->field_machine_name->getString();
```

or

```
 $node->get('field_machine_name')->getString();
```

Comment: You can directly access values with a specific delta:  `$node->field_name[0]->value`

Comment: This worked for single value fields: **$node->get('field_machine_name')->getString();**

Comment: Surely best practice to always use a `get` method rather than access the property directly (`->value`)

Answer (score 36):

For fields you should be able to use `$node->body->value` for example. If you don't know what the field names are I recommend installing the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module for Drupal 8 and inspecting the node via like `dsm($node)`.

Comment: how do you render that field then?

Comment: this seems to be outdated

Comment: @Alex I suggest you ask a new question with the problem you're having. At the time this was an ok answer, it seems disengenous to edit the answer now that is an answer on this page that has more points than this one.

Comment: The linked Acquia slideshow is no longer available.

Comment: Check [this article](https://www.frobiovox.com/posts/2016/03/28/simplify-drupal-8-field-value-calls.html) for a nice explanation.
You can either use $node->field_name->value to get a single value (or first key of multi-value field).
Or you can use $node->field_name->getValue() to get all the values of a field as an array.

Comment: @tenken: Actually, updating an existing answer is preferable over adding a redundant question with new answers.

Answer (score 18):

You can always do `$entity->toArray()` to see what's in an entity. Even when using xdebug (for example with phpstorm) making sense of an entity object on its own is very hard. I doubt `dsm($node)` in Drupal 8 makes any sense. If you insist on in-browser debugging (but you shouldn't, Drupal 8 is too complex to debug without xdebug) `dsm($node->toArray())` is what you want.

Answer (score 17):

Use following code snippet to get node field values

This  is used to get node id from url

```
$nid = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameter($node_id);
```

To load node data using nid

```
$node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load($nid);
```

This is used to get field value.

```
$terms = $node->get('field_Name')->getValue();
```

This is used to get node title.

```
$product_name = $node->getTitle();
```

Comment: Load the node like this: $nid = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameter('node');
      $node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load($nid);

Answer (score 14):

It's simply:

```
$node->get('field_name')->getValue();
```

If the field is an entity reference field, there are some special ways to get the referenced entities.

To get the target id (first element):

```
$entity->get('field_entity_reference')->target_id;
```

To get the loaded entity (first element):

```
$entity->get('field_entity_reference')->entity;
```

When using `->entity` on the field it automatically returns the loaded entity.

If the field can contain multiple references, you can fetch them all like this:

```
$entities = $entity->get('field_entity_reference')->referencedEntities();
```

That will return an array of entities.

Answer (score 7):

For me, having an `$entity` (a node) this worked:

```
$entity->field_name->getValue();
```

using 8.1.

Comment: This one gets all the values of a multi-value field into an array. It can be of course used to get value of single-value field too, however the output will then contain an array with a single value. 
To get a single value of a field (or first value of a multi-value field), use $entity->field_name->value

Answer (score 7):

While using (the actual correct way):

```
$node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($nid);
$node->get('nid')->value; // returns a raw value - Node ID

// Following both returns array structure containing value/target id nested value.
$node->get('nid')->value(); 
$node->nid->getValue();
```

Answer (score 5):

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node

$node = Node::load($nid);
$title = $node->get('title')->value;
```

Or

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node

$title = Node::load($nid)->get('title')->value;
```

Here is nice write up about accessing values from the node object https://www.frobiovox.com/posts/2016/03/28/simplify-drupal-8-field-value-calls.html

Answer (score 4):

When not using nodes but entities (like the OP asked) things get a little more murky.
For example when using an address entity it only took me 8 tries to get the organization value.

```
$v1 = $address->get('field_address_organization')->getString();
$v2 = $address->get('organization')->getString();
$v3 = $address->get('field_organization')->getString();
$v4 = $address->field_organization->getValue();
$v5 = $address->organization->getString();
$v6 = $address->field_organization->getString();
$v7 = $address->organization->getValue();
$v8 = $address->organization;
```

The only one that didn't throw an exception was the last one.  And I'm lying when I say it only took me 8 tries to get the right answer - but 8 is all I'll admit to publicly.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I had to get the address entity and render it programmatically. After a lot of searching and debugging, this is what worked best for me

```
if ($field_name == 'field_address') {
      $render_array = $entity->get($field_name)->view('address_plain');
      $body .= \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($render_array);
    }
```