# How to get a user field in D8?

Tags: entities, users, 8

I am loading a user via [user_load_by_name()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!user!user.module/function/user_load_by_name/8) in my themename.theme. Now I would like to view some of the fields in my template. But how to get/render the fields?

I can use [user_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!user!user.module/function/user_view/8) to render the whole user. But I would like to access only some fields and make them available in the template.

Comment: Does http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/144947/how-do-i-access-a-field-value-for-an-entity-e-g-node-object give you enough to go on?

Comment: @Clive awesome, thanks a lot. `toArray()` works. 
But seems like then we loose information about the fields because when I iterate through them in the template and print them like `{{ field }}` Its not treated  like a field.
So is there a way of transforming them into field objects?

Comment: It think that's something like `$user->field_name->view($display_mode)` @Finn (like https://www.drupal.org/node/2208327)

Comment: @Clive that totally solved my issue. Thanks so much!