# How can I get all fields and values of a node at once?

Tags: 8, entities, nodes

I know how to get a particular field (title field) of a node by following code:

```
$publications = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('node')->load($node_id);
$title = $publications->getTitle();
```

But I need to get all fields and values in that particular node. I tried `print_r($publications)`. Is there any way to get this?

Comment: `print_r($publications->toArray())`, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/144963/47547

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how you can add all values in a custom array. The [`EntityManager`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityManager.php/class/EntityManager/8.8.x) class and the [entity.manager](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.services.yml/service/entity.manager/8.8.x) service are deprecated; you should use the [entity_type.manager](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.services.yml/service/entity_type.manager/8.8.x) service instead.

```
$publications = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('node')
  ->load($node_id);

foreach ($publications->getFields() as $name => $field) {
  $myFields[$name] = $field->getString();
}

kint($myFields);
```

You need to improve this code because for some field types that can be different.

- For multi-value fields you use `$field->getValue()`
- For entity reference fields, `$field->entity->field_name->value`