# How to get fields from taxonomy terms?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I am able to retrieve taxonomy terms programmatically, (as long as I only want to reference the default fields, 'tid' and 'name'). But how do I access custom taxonomy fields?

```
$vid = 'MACHINE_NAME';
$terms = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree($vid);
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $tid = $term->tid;
    $term_name = $term->name;

    // REFERENCE CUSTOM FIELD VALUES HERE...

}
```

I have tried all manor of ways I have seen, but can't get any of them working, eg:

```
$value = $term->FIELD_NAME->value;
$value = $term->get('FIELD_NAME')->getValue();
```

How do I reference custom taxonomy term fields by their machine name, from what is returned by getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree($vid)?

Comment: Either should be correct, but only assuming the field type has a column named `value`. What type of field is it?

Comment: Correct, it depends on the field type. Look here for info about how to get the value from an entity reference field, https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/284658/72672.

Comment: @Clive It's a text field, but I couldn't get either to work earlier. I'm AFK now, so will experiment with getValue() when I get back. Jdrupal, thanks for that useful link!

Comment: Just realised this happened to me before, the answer should help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entities aren't loaded by default (for performance reasons), but [`TermStorage::loadTree`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21taxonomy%21src%21TermStorage.php/function/TermStorage%3A%3AloadTree/8.7.x) takes a `$load_entities` parameter:

> If TRUE, a full entity load will occur on the term objects. Otherwise they are partial objects queried directly from the {taxonomy_term_data} table to save execution time and memory consumption when listing large numbers of terms. Defaults to FALSE.

That will give you access to the fields. E.g.

```
$terms = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('taxonomy_term')
  ->loadTree($vid, 0, NULL, TRUE);
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks @Clive. getValue() returned an array, so I swapped it for getString(), but it's all working now fine!

Comment: Thank you!  That got me much closer to the solution. In my case, I have a known taxonomy id... i just want the machine_name. 
Your code above returns an array with every child of the vocabulary - not the paraent. 

`   An array of term objects that are the children of the vocabulary $vid.`