# Given a taxonomy term id, how do we get the value of other fields; specifically the machine_id?

Tags: entities

A good example of getting the children is posted [How to get fields...](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/286257/how-to-get-fields-from-taxonomy-terms)

I need the machine_id of the parent (or target)

Code below fetches the name;

```
$product_name_id = $product_name_reference->getValue()[0]['target_id'];
$product_name = \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::load($product_name_id)->label();
```

The machine_name is visible under 'values'. How do I get it!

[image]

Comment: You know in PHPstorm, anything visible to you like that, you can right click and "copy path" and it will give you `$foo[bar]->baz[0]['value']` as appropriate?  However, it may be protected, in which case that won't help, and it might not be the recommended way (generally preferable to look for a documented API method), which is why I just mention it as a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @stevekeiretsu which is why I rather use `kint()` than PhpStorm for inspecting variables, [see my guide](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/259108/27710)

Comment: @sea26.2 indeed. If the value is protected, you'll want to take a look at the "Available methods" tab, as [my guide shows](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/259108/27710).

Comment: @NoSssweat I'm very much more a fan of xdebug than kint or any other form of printing, but that 'available methods' tab is cool.  I never realised that was there.  Generally I use PHPStorm for that as well, since if you start typing `$foo->get`, for example, it will offer autocompletes of available getters.  But it's nice to know an alternative, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The **machine name** is the **vid**:
if you search for `machine_id` inside taxonomy module there is no `machine_id` field declared.
[image]

But if you look at [`core/modules/taxonomy/config/schema/taxonomy.schema.yml`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21taxonomy%21config%21schema%21taxonomy.schema.yml/8.2.x) you can see that:

```
vid:
  type: string
  label: 'Machine name'
```

So to get the vid (Machine name) you should use [`getVocabularyId`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21taxonomy%21src%21Entity%21Term.php/function/Term%3A%3AgetVocabularyId/8.2.x)
something like:

```
$product_name_id = $product_name_reference->getValue()[0]['target_id'];;
$product_name = \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::load($product_name_id);
// Vid or machine name.
$vid = $product_name->getVocabularyId();
```

Answer (score 1):

I was way overthinking it...

Solution:

```
$product = $entity->get('field_products')->entity;
$product_name = $product->get('machine_name')->value;
```

$product gets the object from the taxonomy item
$product_name gets machine name