# Get domain from a URL field

Tags: 8

I have a link field in a content type, *field_source*. I created a computed field (*field_source_domain*) in the same content type, which should contain the domain for the link in *field_source*.

I tried with `$value = parse_url('https://subdomain.example.com/foo/bar', PHP_URL_HOST);` and it works, but when I tried `$value = parse_url('$entity->field_source->value', PHP_URL_HOST);` or `$value = parse_url('$fields['field_source']', PHP_URL_HOST);`, I didn't get anything.

How do I get the domain name using a computed field?

Comment: Can you inspect the output of `$entity->field_source->value` and `$fields['field_source']` does it return the full url `https://subdomain.example.com/foo/bar` or something different? like an array or relative url?

Comment: It doesn't return anything. I think this is the problem. I can't get the url from these variables and i can't find the right variable that returns the correct value of the field_source.

Comment: Ok, then you first have to see how to retreive the correct value, have a look at this: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/144947/how-do-i-access-a-field-value-for-an-entity-e-g-node-object  Also the parse_url function only accepts an absolute url so starting whit `https://yourdomain` and not a relative one.

Comment: I tried that but i got a WSOD, i think because the link field has multiple values, title and url. I want only the url and i don't know how to get it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem:

```
$field_source = $entity->get('field_source')->getValue();
$url_link = $field_source[0]['uri'];
$parse = parse_url($url_link);
$value = $parse['host'];
```