# Get all entity reference options from a field name

Tags: entities, 9

I would like to create a node programatically and one field `field_supervisors` has an entity reference field for the node type `People`.

In order to set the correct entity reference information I need to set:

```
[
  ["target_id" => 1],
  ["target_id" => 2],
  // etc..
]
```

How can I get the individual `id` of the entity reference from the `field_supervisors`.
Do I really need to look up the node `People` before to get the id like `$node->id()` or is there a way to return something like this pseudo code:

`Field->field_supervisors->allReferencedEntitiyOptions` which will return all `People` that are available ?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I access a field value for an entity (e.g. node) object?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/144947/how-do-i-access-a-field-value-for-an-entity-e-g-node-object)

Comment: If you want to get the full referenced objects and not just the IDs use https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Entity.php/function/Entity%3A%3AreferencedEntities/8.2.x

Comment: @Hudri thanks for your answer. I don't have a node as I'm creating one. So I need to create the node first and then set the reference entities field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I really need to look up the node People before to get the id

Yes, there's no auto-magic method for that. It's not a lot of code though. Without DI, for example:

```
$ids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->condition('type', 'person')->execute();
```

Comment: thanks, I was hoping there is a way to return all entity reference options a certain field has, but that will do the job.

Comment: You could pull the ER field apart and I'm sure find the code to do that based on the field settings, but if you already know the conditions you want it seems like a waste of effort